# .fullcalendar is not a function on Submit Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I am working on Fullcalendar and I am not able to render event. 
I am opening a Bootstrap Modal on clicking anywhere on calendar. 
After entering all the info when I click on Submit I need to render the changes in Calendar but its saying 'fullcalendar is not a function. 
I called FullCalender while loading as well and it worked perfectly but I think I am doing something wrong when I call FullCalendar on Submit button.

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

            <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

            <!-- Optional theme -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

            <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->

            <script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
            <script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
            <script src="http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
            <script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
            <script src='http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fullcalendar/1.5.4/gcal.js'></script>
            <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js'></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.4.0/fullcalendar.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
            <title>Bootstrap Scheduler</title>
            <h3 class="text-center">Bootstrap Scheduler</h3>
            <style>
            .nopadding {
                padding-left: 0px;
            }
            </style>
            </head>
            <body>
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                        header: {
                                    left: 'prev,next today',
                                    center: 'title',
                                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                                },
                         defaultView: 'month',
                         editable: true,
                         selectable: true,
                          //header and other values
                          select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                              endtime = moment(end).format('h:mm tt');
                              starttime = moment(start).format('ddd, MMM d, h:mm tt');
                              var mywhen = starttime + ' - ' + endtime;
                              $('#createEventModal #apptStartTime').val(start);
                              $('#createEventModal #apptEndTime').val(end);
                              $('#createEventModal #apptAllDay').val(allDay);
                              $('#createEventModal #when').text(mywhen);
                              jQuery.noConflict();
                              $('#createEventModal').modal('show');
                                }
                });

                $('#submitButton').on('click', function(e){
                                $("#createEventModal").modal('hide');
                                alert("form submitted");
                                var newEvent = {
                                        title: $('#eventTitle').val(),
                                        start: new Date($('#apptStartTime').val()),
                                        end: new Date($('#apptEndTime').val()),
                                        allDay: ($('#apptAllDay').val() == "true"),
                                };

                                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                                    newEvent,
                                    true);

                            });                 

                });


            </script>
            <div class="container" id="calendar"></div>

            <div id="createEventModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Create new event</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <h5>Event Title</h5>
                            <input id="eventTitle" type="text" class="form-control"></input>
                            <input type="hidden" id="apptAllDay" />
                            <h5>Link to loan file</h5>
                            <select class="form-control">
                              <option value="loanPicker">Loan Picker / Search</option>
                            </select>

                            <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class='col-sm-3 nopadding'>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    <h5>Start date & time</h5>
                                        <div class='input-group date' id='apptStartTime'>
                                            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class='col-sm-3'>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h5>End date & time</h5>
                                        <div class='input-group date' id='apptEndTime'>
                                            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div >
                        </div>
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                $(document).ready(function() {
                                        $('#apptStartTime').datetimepicker();
                                        $('#apptEndTime').datetimepicker();
                                    });
                                </script>
                            </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button id="submitButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


            </body>
```

[image]

Comment: You're including two versions of jQuery and jQueryUI. That's never going to go well for a start.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes, if I remove even a single one then its throwing an exception

Comment: Where in the code is action to show modal on click on calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

### [Here is a codepen.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BoJwGm)

1. Moved `id='apptStartTime'` and `id='apptEndTime'` to inputs (you had them in divs).

---

2. Changed selectors in Javascript for datempicker (it is related to first issue).

---

3. Added button below calendar to open the modal.

---

HTML:

```
<h3 class="text-center">Bootstrap Scheduler</h3>

<div class="container" id="calendar">
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createEventModal">Create Event</button>
</div>

<div id="createEventModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Create new event</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h5>Event Title</h5>
        <input id="eventTitle" type="text" class="form-control"></input>
        <input type="hidden" id="apptAllDay" />
        <h5>Link to loan file</h5>
        <select class="form-control">
          <option value="loanPicker">Loan Picker / Search</option>
        </select>

        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class='col-sm-3 nopadding'>
              <div class="form-group">
                <h5>Start date & time</h5>
                <div class='input-group date'>
                  <input type='text' id='apptStartTime' class="form-control" />
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-sm-3'>
              <div class="form-group">
                <h5>End date & time</h5>
                <div class='input-group date'>
                  <input type='text' class="form-control" id='apptEndTime' />
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button id="submitButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
.nopadding {
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.btn {
  margin-top: 20px !important;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultView: 'month',
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    //header and other values
    select: function(start, end, allDay) {
      endtime = moment(end).format('h:mm tt');
      starttime = moment(start).format('ddd, MMM d, h:mm tt');
      var mywhen = starttime + ' - ' + endtime;
      jQuery('#createEventModal #apptStartTime').val(start);
      jQuery('#createEventModal #apptEndTime').val(end);
      jQuery('#createEventModal #apptAllDay').val(allDay);
      jQuery('#createEventModal #when').text(mywhen);
      jQuery.noConflict();
      $('#createEventModal').modal('show');
    }
  });

  $('#submitButton').on('click', function(e) {
    $("#createEventModal").modal('hide');
    var newEvent = {
      title: $('#eventTitle').val(),
      start: new Date($('#apptStartTime').val()),
      end: new Date($('#apptEndTime').val()),
      allDay: ($('#apptAllDay').val() == "true"),
    };

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent',
      newEvent,
      true);

  });

});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#apptStartTime').parent().datetimepicker();
  $('#apptEndTime').parent().datetimepicker();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue related to date but still I am finding exception when I add an event. Are you able to add an event when you save the Event?

Comment: The code breaks if I click on any part of the Calendar and then if I want to add the event . My objective was to click on the desired date which can populate the modal (start and end time) and when I save I can see the event on calendar.

Comment: Good idea by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in my code. I had to do the following to make it work:

- Remove the duplicate jquery.min.js & jQuery.ui.min
- Remove jQuery.noConflict()
- Substitute $ with 'jQuery' all over the code.

Thanks to @Rory and @makshh